# how to do something when liferay module stop

Tags: liferay, osgi

i am making cron job like loop to do something using new thread.

when module stop, this thread keeps running, so when i deployed updated module, i'm afraid it will make duplicate thread doing similar task

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = ExportImportLifecycleListener.class)
public class StaticUtils extends Utils{
    
private StaticUtils() {}
    
    private static class SingletonHelper{
        private static final StaticUtils INSTANCE = new StaticUtils();
    }
        
    public static StaticUtils getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    
}


public class Utils extends  BaseExportImportLifecycleListener{
    public Utils() {
        startTask();
    }
    protected Boolean CRON_START = true;

    private void startTask() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (CRON_START) {
                    System.out.println("test naon bae lah ");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() {
        CRON_START = false;
        System.out.println(
                "cron stop lah woooooooooooooooooy");
    }
}
```

i'm using liferay 7

I have populated task that i store from db, so this thread is checking is there a task that it must do, then if it exist execute it.

I'm quite new in osgi and liferay. i've try to use scheduler and failed and also exportimportlifecycle listener but dont really get it yet

Answer (score 0):

1. think again: Do you really need something to run all the time in the background, or do you just need some asynchronous processing in the background, when triggered? It might be better to start a background task as a one-off, that automatically terminates
2. Liferay provides an internal MessageBus, that you can utilize to listen to events and implement background processing, without the need for a custom thread
3. You're in the OSGi world, so you can utilize @Activate, @Modified, @Deactivate (from `org.osgi.service.component.annotations`) or use a `org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator`.

But, in general, it's preferable if you don't start your own thread

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, i've updated the question, adding some more detail. Do you have a link for message bus that i can use?